# Show Messagebox when Windows X close button is pressed

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        app.atexit.connect(self.exitApp)

    def exitApp(self):
        atexit.register(self.exitApp(app))
        ret = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(None, 'Close request', 'Are you sure you want to quit?',
                                         QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No,
                                         QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes)
        if ret == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            sys.exit(app.exec())
        elif ret == QtGui.QMessageBox.No:
            pass

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(1280, 760)
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))

def main():
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.showMaximized()
    Ui_MainWindow.loadData(ui)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main()
```

I want to show a message box showing "Are you sure you want to quit?" when user clicks on Windows Close button (X button on top).

How do I get a signal when user clicks on the button?

Solution will probably be similar to [Detect when the "x" or close button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764489/detect-when-the-x-or-close-button-is-pressed)    but I am using PyQt4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to overwrite the closeEvent method and ignore the event if you do not want the window to close. I have modified your code a little because I had problems reproducing it.

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        ret = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(None, 'Close request', 'Are you sure you want to quit?',
                                         QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No,
                                         QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes)
        if ret == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            QtGui.QMainWindow.closeEvent(self, event)
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I close Python and no message box appeared. Thank you for responding to my questions @eyllanesc I noticed you have been answering some of my questions previously.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with how the code and UI is structured. When I add ui.show(), it shows a small window with no content. When I try to close it, the message box appears but with my mainwindow which contains the system, it doesn't.