# How to execute a function on exit (exit code -1 especially - when closing program by "X" button)

Tags: python, python-3.x, exit

I would like to save some variables to pickle file on exit, although closing the program by the user (exit code -1, by pressing the "X" button) do not trigger the .atexit functions.

How can I do this?

Comment: how exactly is the user exiting? you can use signals if way of user exit is known.

Comment: You can also handle exit signal of the OS. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18499497/952747)

Comment: By closing the program manually ( 'X' button)

Comment: What is the "X button"? Is it of terminal or is it GUI of your program?

Comment: My OS is Windows. I'm currently running it in Python - python.exe (or in PyCharm interpreter), although I would like to make a GUI for it someday

Comment: Pycharm does not use X button to stop a script. By default at least. It uses `ctrl+F2` to send SIGINT / SIGKILL.

Comment: Well, take a look: https://repl.it/@PiotrGoldys/LumberingThoseFunction

It saves the data when the program exits by itsef (as specified). I would like to make it save data also when stopped manually, by clicking "stop"

Comment: `atexit` will only work if your program exits cleanly. If you stop the interpreter in its tracks they won't be called. It's the interpreter that executes those functions and it can't do that if you have stopped it. You will have to provide a more elegant way to exit your program than simply killing the interpreter process.

Comment: I know that `atexit` won't work in this case. Just wondering if there is some method to handle it, without creating "elegant way to exit program"

Comment: I came up with an idea of using threading, to create thread in which I specify, that program will close after some input, lets say "s".
How can I make it just "idle" in background and wait for "exit input"?

`def out():
    if input() == "s":
        exit()   # Exit command which works with `atexit` - didnt check if this command will do it yet

t1 = threading.Thread(target=out)
t1.start()`
Here is what i came up with, although it overrides the whole program and makes it wait for input, instead of toing it in the background

Comment: Or maybe it would be better to make a GUI using tkinker and follow with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764489/detect-when-the-x-or-close-button-is-pressed?rq=1
?